# Is jQuery free to use in commercial production?

Tags: jquery, licensing

Can I use jquery to build a commercial app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a word, yes.

http://jquery.org/license

> You are free to use a jQuery project in commercial projects as long as the copyright header is left intact.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely, jQuery is [licensed](http://jquery.org/license) under the MIT license. The MIT license states you can use the project in commercial projects.

See [wiki mit license page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) for further information.

jQuery used to be dual licensed under MIT and GPL, but this was removed in [September 2012].[3](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/09/10/jquery-licensing-changes/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, as long you keep the credits.

[jQuery is licensed](http://jquery.org/license) under [GNU GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html) and MIT licences, and with the [MIT licence](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) you could use it in commercial applications.